# Making python multiprocessing more resources efficient

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I have a very sample python code that goes trough some URLs, make a get request for each URL parse the source code using Beachful Soup to get some data ,store the data in a CSV file using pandas.

I have a huge list or URLs this is why I wanted to use multiprocessing/threading to run like 50 instances of the code, however I could only run like 5 instances of the code using multiprocessing even though I have a good machine and the code is not that heavy I think.

The code looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_and_save(urls):
    for url in urls:
        page = get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page , 'html.parser')

        href = soup.find("a")["href"]
        pd.DataFrame({'link':href}).to_csv(f'{url}.csv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls_to_parse = [....]
    processes = []
    for urls in urls_to_parse[::1000]:
       p = Process(target=parse_and_save , args=(urls,).start()
       processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

I tried using Threading and multiprocessing but nothing works, the CPU usage just goes to 100% and I can not do anything else, Is there a way to solve that ? Or I will need to use another programming language ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each new process/thread requires additional resources. So the correct way is to use a pool of them (usualy no more than some tenths), and map the urls on that pool.

Comment: I've tried this, but I still can not run more than 20 scraper, and I still want to run more.

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved using `concurrent.futures`, the majority of the time spent running the code is waiting for server responses, not for processors to complete tasks. There is no need to split the task over processors you can easily use threads like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import concurrent.futures

def parse_and_save(urls):
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'html.parser')

        href = soup.find("a")["href"]
        pd.DataFrame({'link':href}).to_csv(f'{url}.csv') #not sure your code will work?

urls_to_parse = [....]
workers = 50 #can change this, experiment to find best performance before GIL starts slowing you down: https://realpython.com/python-gil/
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    final_list = executor.map(parse_and_save, urls_to_parse)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I still can not run more than 20 scraper, and I still want to run more.